# Examples of noetherian local rings $R$ such that $K'_0(R)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

Does there exist a simple example of a commutative noetherian local ring $R$ such that $K'_0(R) = K_0(\mbox{Mod-}R)$ (by $\mbox{Mod-}R$ I mean the abelian category of finitely generated $R$-modules)  is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Do you mean $R$ to be commutative?

Comment: $\mathbb Q[X,Y]/(XY)$ localized at the origin. Or maybe you wanted a domain.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}[[t^2,t^3]]$ should work.

Comment: Does it? It's clear that the group is generated by the free module of rank one and the residue field. But the latter is trivial in the group. (There is a principal ideal of codimension $2$ and another of codimension $3$.)

Comment: @TomGoodwillie How one can compute K' of your example?

Comment: @YCor Yes, but if you have a good noncommutative example, it will be interesting too.

Comment: By $\operatorname{Mod}_R$, do you mean *finitely generated* $R$-modules?

Comment: In my example there are two independent maps to $\mathbb Z$ given by doing two things to a module $M$: look at the rank of $M/YM$ as a module for localized $\mathbb Q[X]$, and look at the rank of $M/XM$ as a module for localized $\mathbb Q[Y]$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Thank you! But how we can see that they are *really* independent? It sounds very natural and intuitive, but how one can provide the formal argument?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes, you are right, I would have to write more accurately.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie: Sorry, I don't understand your argument. Are you saying that the residue field is the quotient of a principal ideal by another one? That would mean that it has finite projective dimension, which is not the case.

Comment: @abx: $M=\mathbb Q[[t]]$ is a module over your ring, and the exact sequence $M \to M\to \mathbb Q$ shows that $\mathbb Q$ is zero in the Grothendieck group.

Comment: @Hailong Dao: Ah, nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just to flesh out @Tom Goodwillie example.

For any reasonable scheme $X$ and an open set $U$, one has a natural exact sequence,

$$K_0(X-U)\to K_0(X)\to K_0(U)\to 0.$$

Taking $X=\operatorname{Spec} (\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/xy)_{(x,y)}$ (or a number of similar examples) and $U$ the punctured spectrum, we note that the punctured spectrum is two points and thus $K_0(U)=\mathbb{Z}^2$. The kernel is generated by the closed point, but going mod $x+y, x+y^2$, one can easily see that 2 and 3 times the closed point is zero in $K_0(X)$. So, we get $K_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}^2$.